# OnTouch delay (Android)

Tags: android

I have an app where I need to have a delay after each touch in an ImageButton.

I tried the Thread.sleep() method, but I am not sure if this is the best way to deal with it.

What do you guys recommend?

Any help is appreciatted!

ONE MORE THING: I want the content of the onTouch() event to be fired THEN I want to delay "X" seconds the next onTouch() event. It's like to prevent the user to click too many times in the button.

Comment: Perhaps a bit more about what you are trying to do... are you trying to have an event happen after a delay? then `Handler.postDelayed()` might be the right solution

Comment: JRaymond, could you post some sample code please? I am a noob! =)

Comment: I would, but Pavel's answer is pretty much exactly what i'd have told you to do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all touch events are handled by UI thread, `Thread.sleep()` will block your UI thread which is (I hope) not what you are looking for.
I think the most correct way to solve your problem would be using `postDelayed(Runnable, long)` interface in your `onClick` handler which allows your to delay execution:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // do your stuff here
        }
    }, 10000); //10sec delay
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want user to prevent clicking too fast on your image view, I strongly recommend go with `onClick` rather than `onTouch` (unless there are serious reasons for that)

However, please see the code snippet which might help you:

```
private boolean blocked = false;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        if (!blocked)
        {
            blocked = true;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    blocked = false;
                }
            }, 1000);
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Pavel Dudka. I am using the onTouch() event... is it possible to use your solution with onTouch(), too?

Comment: sure, but as you know onTouch gets called not once per user interaction, so you might want to introduce some flags to run your delayed stuff only once, or check type of motion event (for instance react only on `ACTION_DOWN` events. Depends on your needs basically...

Comment: Hello again Pavel. Thank you for your reply. I am using the ACTION_DOWN event to make sure I get it just once. I tried to use your code but the compiler says I need to create the method postDelayed and that I must declare the arg1 of onTouch() event as final. How can I correct that?

Comment: Hello Pavel, thank you for your updated solution. I tried it, but it still asks me to create the method postDelayed. Anyway, let me post the question in a better way: I want to prevent double clicks (maybe triple clicks or even more). I was seeing in some other threads that setting the button to clickable = false doesn't work. I need to prevent these double/triple clicks by setting a time (in ms) when the next touch is acceptable. What do you think?

Comment: the reason why compiler asks you to create `postDelayed` method is that you are probably using custom touch handler, but not that one which is provided by Activity. You need to create Handler then. See my updated answer