# Android onPressed with delay

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have tried with pure XML files and also by using the onEvent options in the Java files. Both fails to do what I want.

What I need is to add onPressed events to View objects in order to change the background depending on the state. It does work, or at least it is changing the background. However in all the applications I have seen for Android, there is some kind of delay on the Views onPressed state, so in case the user presses the screen and start scrolling, the background does not change. In my case however they always do. So I get this annoying blinking of the View objects every time I attempt to scroll.

How do I go about this to make the onPressed work correctly?

Comment: one suggest is that you can implement the onTouch interface.. 
it will give you those action : DOWN,MOVE,UP
so when the user press the DOWN event is occur and you can change the background, but if he is still pressing and moving the finger on the screen the MOVE event is occur and then you can write you're scrolling code

Comment: I have already tried that. The down event is triggered before the move event which produces the blinking effect

Comment: Ok, so you can declare a boolean variable (set to false) which tells you if the user already pressed.. 
When the down event is triggered set the variable to true
and when "up" event is triggered set it to false again.. and one more thing.. in the down event.. check if the boolean variable is true -> if so then do nothing, else -> change the background

Comment: Now I understand what you're trying to do.. check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327626/ontouch-delay-android

Comment: This seams to be something usable. I will try to play around with this, thank you so much :)